# two way data bind in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-4

I know this question would be asked many times before but i am still having some issues with data binding in Angular JS.Well I have a case where user is posting updates from partial page and showing it on other partial.Lets take example using laravel blade:

```
@extends('layouts/index')
 @section
   @include(header)
   @include(postpage)
   @include(showingpostpage)
   @include(footer)
 @endsection
```

Now thing is that if user is posting from postpage and i would be showing his updates in showingpostpage page. So in this case how two-way data binding gonna work?

So far i have come across this

```
var Test= angular.module('Test',[],function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{=');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('=}');
    });


Test.factory('myService', function($rootScope,$http) {
       return {
         getmeout: function(callback){
           $http.get(baseurl+"ajax/getall").success(callback)
         },

       }
    });

function GetHoot(myService,$scope, $http,$location)
    {

    $scope.comments = [];

    myService.getmeout(function(data){  
            $scope.comments=data;

            });


  $scope.addComment =function(){
           var hoot = $scope.comment.hoot;
             $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';           
             $http({
                method : "POST",
               url :baseurl+ "ajax/hoot",
               data : "hoot="+hoot
            }).success(function(data){             
             $scope.comments=data;             
             $scope.comments.push($scope.comment);
             $scope.comment.hoot = "";   

     });
 }
 $scope.$watch('comments', function(newValue, oldValue){         
     if(newValue != oldValue){  
         console.log($scope.comments);      
        $scope.comments= newValue;
     }       
     });

 }
```

Whenever user input something i can see updated things in log but it doesn't reflect on view.
  My view 
      postpage view:

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-controller="GetHoot">
<form name="myForm">
                 <input name="hoot" class="title_input" id="hooted" ng-model="comment.hoot" type="text" ng-minlength="2">
                  </div>
                  <div class="profile_right_main01_b_2"><input type="submit" ng-click="addComment(comment.hoot)" class="post" name="submit" value="Post"></div>
                  </div>
                   </form>
  </div>
```

And showingpostpage html :

```
 <div ng-app="Test" id="ng-app" ng-controller="GetHoot">
   <div ng-repeat="comment in comments" >
    {=comment.hoot=}
   </div>
  </div>
```

I can only see updates when i refresh view? Kindly help

Comment: This same question was asked 4 times. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

one suggestion is forming the html with the hole page in consideration. The way you are doing, two instances of the same controller are in action at the same time in your page

Just as an example to illustrate, your general html should look like this:

```
@extends('layouts/index')
 @section
 <div ng-app="Test">
    @include(header)
    <div ng-controller="GetHoot">
       @include(postpage)
       @include(showingpostpage)
    </div>
    @include(footer)
 </div>
 @endsection
```

And remove the ng-app and ng-controller from your postpage and showingpostpage.
That way your page will have only one instance of your controller in action and the binding should finally get working.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this is not working and even it wouldn't be the recommended solution. I know their is some scope concept, even i used it but my angular view isn't recongnizing it.

Comment: If you post your final html code, I can point out how it should look like in order to work.